# Sensor with integrated ID

Tags: electrical

I'm looking for another solution to a problem.

I have 4 of the same infrared sensors which detect if an object is close or not (pretty simple). The difficult part now is that they don't have an integrated ID, so I can't see which of them is detecting something. I would like to use the least amount of wiring, for example an I2C solution.

Right now I'm using a kind of DIP-switch configuration (a connector in which the sensor cables are added and a simple wire bridge to create a ID) to set the sensor apart. Although this works, it requires a lot of cables.

I was thinking of an analog solution. Putting some resistors after the sensor all in parallel and checking the voltage. But I was hoping someone would know of a better solution.

The current sensor is a photoelectric sensor ([BOS 5K-NS-RD11-02](https://www.balluff.com/en/de/productfinder/product/?key=BOS011A#/)) from Balluff, but that's not the point. Maybe someone has a better option. I use CANopen, but I can also use something else like I2C.

I'm curious if anybody has used more of these simple sensors and managed to assign them a different ID or is there a photoelectric sensor that already has something where you can assign an ID to it?

Comment: What is the sensor, or at least, what is the technology?  Do they just output a voltage?  Are they resistive sensors?  On/off devices, like a Hall switch?

Comment: Can you be more specific, which sensor do you use, are you looking different sensors or just a solution for what you already have? The solution with resistors is pretty good if you don't have noise issues.

Comment: You need to give more information. Most of all: What are the sensors connected to? What kind of signal do you need? What kind of wiring do you want? How should the signal be evaluated?

Comment: Your question doesn't explain why one wire from each sensor to the controller is not suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Add a 1Wire serial number from Dallas like DS2401 for logical id then you should power each sensor to match their physical location with their logical id. then make a table in your code so you know which sensor you are reading.
I made something like this and it worked. aorry I do not have more time to explain. Sure many pros here they can help you, if I get your problem right.